# Как добавить в приложение новую форму добавление заказа с сайта?

Tags: android

У меня приложение клиент-сервер. Все данные (категории, заказы, список заказов) добавляются через сайт. А мне нужно, чтобы пользователи через приложение  добавляли свои заказы. Все работает, кроме "Добавить заказ".

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    MyApp = com.app.jobs.MyApplication.getInstance();
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    LatestFragment homeFragment = new LatestFragment();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Container, homeFragment).commit();

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_go_add_job:
                    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.menu_add_job));
                    AddJobFragment currentAddJob = new AddJobFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Container, currentAddJob).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_go_latest:
                    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.menu_latest));
                    LatestFragment homeFragment = new LatestFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Container, homeFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_go_category:
                    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.menu_category));
                    CategoryFragment currentCategory = new CategoryFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Container, currentCategory).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_go_favourite:
                    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.menu_favourite));
                    FavouriteFragment favouriteFragment = new FavouriteFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Container, favouriteFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_go_about:
                    Intent about = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.app.jobs.AboutUsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(about);
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_go_privacy:
                    Intent privacy = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.app.jobs.PrivacyActivity.class);
                    startActivity(privacy);
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_go_profile:
                    Intent profile = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.app.jobs.ProfileActivity.class);
                    profile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(profile);
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_go_logout:
                    Logout();
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_go_rate:
                    RateApp();
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_go_share:
                    ShareApp();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: и чё за проблема?

Comment: выдает ошибку. Мне нужно форму с сайта, в приложение запихать.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает? Выложите стектрэйс.